# Replacing a BufferedInputStream with a byte array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedinputstream

The following code reads data from a file using a BufferedInputStream and processes it in chuncks. I would like to modify this code so that instead of the data coming from a file through a stream, I would like to have it come from a byte array. I have already read the file's data into a byte array and I want to use this while...loop to process the array data instead of working with the data from the file stream. Not sure how to do it:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
BufferedInputStream origin = new BufferedInputStream(in, BUFFER);

int count;

while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1)
{
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: where is the byte array(in your code)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) to wrap your existing byte array into an `InputStream` so that you can read from the byte array as from any other `InputStream`:

```
byte[] buffer = {1,2,3,4,5};
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);

byte[] chunk = new byte[2];
while(is.available() > 0) {
    int count = is.read(chunk);
    if (count == chunk.length) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chunk));
    } else {
        byte[] rest = new byte[count];
        System.arraycopy(chunk, 0, rest, 0, count);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rest));
    } 
}
```

```
Output:
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5]
```

Comment: Does that work if the size off the array is odd? You have an even sized array and are reading in 2 bytes. What if the array was 7 bytes long? On the last loop it only reads in one byte?

Comment: @AndroidDev Was still working on this while you posted your comment :D See my updated code. BTW: It would also have worked before, but the last chunk would have contained data from the previous read. In any case, you need to check the return value from `is.read()` to check how many bytes have actually been read, or use the return value from `is.available()` to see if a whole chunk is still available. There are several possibilities to solve this - probably `System.arraycopy()` is not the best one ...

Answer (score 1):

The following will read all the data from FileInputStream into byte array:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream (file);
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
byte [] buffer = new byte [65536];
int l;
while ((l = input.read (buffer)) > 0)
    output.write (buffer, 0, l);
input.close ();
output.close ();
byte [] data = output.toByteArray ();
```